# build.phonegap.com version of android app

Tags: android, cordova

I created Adroid app in which I want to check the location of the mobile phone. I started the emulator install the app and every time I want to check It fails. Is the emulator the problem (bacause it os not a real mobile phone) or I did not do it correctly.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
        <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width, height=device-height, target-densitydpi=device-dpi" />
                <title>Hello World</title>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova-2.1.0.js"></script>
        <script text="text/javascript">
        function startUp(){
            document.getElementById("H1").innerHTML = "Checking your location...";
           document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false)
        }
        function onDeviceReady() {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(onSuccess, onError);
    }

    // onSuccess Geolocation
    //
    function onSuccess(position) {
        var element = document.getElementById('location');
        element.innerHTML = 'Latitude: '           + position.coords.latitude              + '<br />' +
                            'Longitude: '          + position.coords.longitude             + '<br />' +
                            'Altitude: '           + position.coords.altitude              + '<br />';
                            document.getElementById("H1").innerHTML = "";
    }

    // onError Callback receives a PositionError object
    //
    function onError(error) {
        document.getElementById("H1").innerHTML = "Fail to check your location.";
    }

        </script>
    </head>
    <body style="margin:0px;" onload="startUp()" bgcolor="#000">
        <div class="app" style="background-color:#4D4D4D">
            <font color="#FF9900" size="2"><h1 id="H1" style="font-family:courier new;"></h1></font>
            <p id="location"></p>
        </div>



    </body>
</html>
```

The HTML5 file and config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
    <widget xmlns = "http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets"
        xmlns:gap = "http://phonegap.com/ns/1.0"
        id        = "com.park.manager"
        versionCode="10" 
        version   = "0.1.9">
    <name>ParkingManager</name>
    <description>
        A system, which manages parking side areas.
    </description>
    <author href="" email="">
        Parking Side Manager Team
    </author>
    <preference name="phonegap-version" value="2.1.0" />
    <preference name="orientation" value="landscape" />
    <preference name="target-device" value="universal" />
    <preference name="fullscreen" value="true" />
    <preference name="android-installLocation" value="auto" />
    <icon src="icon.png" />
    <gap:splash src="splash.png" />
    <feature name="http://api.phonegap.com/1.0/geolocation"/>
    <feature name="http://api.phonegap.com/1.0/network"/>

</widget>
```

Answer (score 0):

make sure that in your manifest XML you add the permissions for coarse and fine location.

phone gap has its upsides, but it will not fix some of your main problems like having to do the manifest by hand. If you made your app in java before you know how to add these permissions. if not use  to check how to do it.[permissions](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/security/permissions.html)

besides that your cordova geolaction call is right, I have used it before from their examples.

Answer (score 0):

The last time I worked with PhoneGap the manifest already had the correct permissions in the manifest file.

You most likely need to provide mock data for the emulator.
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/location/strategies.html#MockData

Answer (score 0):

its the emulator, you need a real phone because the emulator is a pain in the you know what to get to work correctly. your Javascript and html are fine.